# Generate a unique key by encoding 4 smaller numeric primitive types into a long (Int64)

Tags: c#, hash, bitwise-operators

I have the following method which *should* create a unique long for any combination of the provided params:

```
private static long GenerateKey(byte sT, byte srcT, int nId, ushort aId)
{
    var nBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(nId);
    var aBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(aId);

    var byteArray = new byte[8];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(new[] { sT}, 0, byteArray, 7, 1);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(new[] { srcT}, 0, byteArray, 6, 1);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(aBytes, 0, byteArray, 4, 2);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(nBytes, 0, byteArray, 0, 4);


    var result = BitConverter.ToInt64(byteArray, 0);

    return result;
}
```

So I end up with:

```
   1    2   3   4    5   6   7   8    
------------------------------------
|byte|byte| ushort |      int      |
------------------------------------
```

Can this be done with bitwise operations? I tried the below but seemed to generate the same number for different values??

```
var hash = ((byte)sT << 56) ^ ((byte)srcT<< 48) ^ (aId << 32) ^ nId;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do it with bitwise operators? Does it just have to be collision free or produce the same result as your example?

Comment: Well I guess I felt that the single line `<<` variant would be more easily understood by the next dev, when they stumble upon this in a few years.  Yes, it's used a dictionary key so most definately needs to be collison free.

Comment: Thinking on this, whilst this will avoid all collisions, which is good but not necessary for hash functions, more importantly, a small change in value should result in a large change in hash. With this approach, this will not be achieved, one operand will be the least siginificant.

Comment: Perhaps, `Hash` should be changed to `GenerateKey`?

Comment: That would align better, semantically. You could also consider returning `ulong`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What went wrong here is that something like this

```
((byte)sT << 56)
```

does not do what you want. What it actually does, is cast `sT` to a `byte` (which it already is), then it's implicitly converted to an `int` (because you do math with it), and then it's shifted left by 24 (shift counts are masked to limit them to less than the size of the left operand).

So actually instead of casting to a narrow type, you should cast to a wide type, like this:

```
((long)sT << 56)
```

Also, note that implicitly converting an `int` to `long` sign-extends it, which means that if `nId` is negative, you would end up complementing all the other fields (xor with all ones is complement).

So try this:

```
((long)sT << 56) | ((long)srcT << 48) | ((long)aId << 32) | (nId & 0xffffffffL)
```

I've also changed the xor's to or's, it's more idiomatic for combining non-overlapping things.

Comment: +1, I also wanted to say a word about the `|` instead of `^`, but forgot.

Answer (score 3):

In the following line:

```
var hash = ((byte)sT << 56) ^ ((byte)srcT<< 48) ^ (aId << 32) ^ nId;
```

You are shifting more bits than the types are capable of holding. You can't shift a `byte` more than 8 bits, the rest is lost. Conversely, an `ushort` cannot be shifted more than 16 bits. Just cast everything to `long` and you'll get the expected result:

```
var hash = ((long)sT << 56)
         ^ ((long)srcT << 48)
         ^ ((long)aId << 32)
         ^ (uint)nId; // Cast to uint is required to prevent sign extension
```

Comment: Slightly dangerous if `nId` can be negative though